# signalR connection id required in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, web, signalr

I had a project with Asp.net core and I completed it
Now I want to add SignalR to it

i try add signalR to my asp.net core project
but i have an error
it is "connection id required"
i feel my error is in startup file

My Hub class and My Controller is in Chat Area(an Area called it Chat)

it is my startup file:

```
using CoreLayer.Services.Chats;
using CoreLayer.Services.Chats.ChatGroups;
using CoreLayer.Services.Users.UserGroups;
using Echat.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using SendEmail;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TopCoderZ.Core.Service;
using TopCoderZ.Core.Service.Interface;
using TopCoderZ.Core.Services;
using TopCoderZ.Core.Services.Interfaces;
using TopCoderZ.DataLayer.Context;
using TopLearn.Core.Services;

namespace FarsLearn.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        public string CookieAuthenticateSchemeDefaults { get; private set; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var environment = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();


            services.AddDataProtection()
                    .SetApplicationName($"my-app-{environment.EnvironmentName}")
                    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo($@"{environment.ContentRootPath}\keys"));
            //services.AddMvc();
            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
            services.AddRazorPages();
            //services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => { options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 6000000; });

            #region Authentication

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(43200);

            });

            #endregion
            #region DbContext
            services.AddDbContext<TopCoderZContext>(p =>
            {
                p.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TopCoderZConnection"));
            });
            #endregion
            #region IoC
            services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
            services.AddTransient<IViewRenderService, RenderViewToString>();
            services.AddTransient<IPermissionService, PermissionService>();
            services.AddTransient<ICourseService, CourseService>();
            services.AddTransient<IOrderService, OrderService>();
            services.AddTransient<IPostService, PostService>();
            services.AddTransient<IForumService, ForumService>();

            services.AddScoped<IChatService, ChatService>();
            services.AddScoped<IChatGroupService, ChatGroupService>();

            services.AddScoped<IUserGroupService, UserGroupService>();
            #endregion
            **services.AddSignalR();**
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next();
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error404");
                }
            });

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.Value.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith("/coursefilesonline"))
                {
                    var callingUrl = context.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
                    if (callingUrl != "" && (callingUrl.StartsWith("https://farslearn.com/") || callingUrl.StartsWith("http://farslearn.com/")))
                    {
                        await next.Invoke();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Login");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await next.Invoke();
                }


            });


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            //app.UseMvc(routes =>
            //{
            //    routes.MapRoute(
            //        name: "areas",
            //        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"

            //    );
            //    routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            //}); app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(

                    name: "MyAreas",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                **endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");**
            });
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("FarsLearn || XXX Big Error");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

i have an error

it is "connection id required"
what should i do?
please help me

Answer (score 2):

reza jan

at ConfigureServices:

```
        // SignalR step 1
        services.AddSignalR();
        // SignalR step 3
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("SignalRClientPolicy", policy =>
            {
                policy.AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "https://www.me.com")
                    .AllowCredentials();
            });
        });
```

at Configure:

```
        // SignalR step 4
        app.UseCors("SignalRClientPolicy");

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            // SignalR setp 2
            endpoints.MapHub<MainHub>("/MainHubEndpoint_rE4Tt3");
        });
```